# Java NUX library, XPATH Performance

Tags: java, xpath

I am using the NUX library to run
~20 xpaths queries on an XML ~20KB in two different settings, one in a
JUnit test, the other inside a bean in a Jetty servlet (hence running
in a multi-threaded scenario.) It seems like when ran in Junit, it is
evaluating the XPaths in ~8ms, whereas in the Jetty servlet it is
taking ~80ms to evaluate. In both cases, the XPaths and the XML files
are the same. What could be causing this performance difference? Could
Jetty or another service be overwriting NUX/SAX's configuration?
Please note that when I am running this comparison, there is no other
computation hapening in the Jetty servlet, and the servlet is
configured to have a single executer thread.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one else has opined, here are some possibilities:

- Since the server is multi-threaded, it may be experiencing contention for other threads.
- The available memory to the servlet is likely different than the available memory to the JUnit test. Try increasing the amount of memory allowed for servlets.